# Boost serialization exception error

Tags: c++, exception, serialization, boost

I have recently ran into an error when compiling my program with the boost serialization library.

I have read across many forums that I need to link the boost serialization library (-lboost_serialization). Which, I did.

However, there is one error that I am getting on the code:

```
/usr/local/boost_1_64_0/boost/serialization/throw_exception.hpp:36: undefined reference to `boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)'
```

So I thought, what if I have to also include the exception library?
So I added this into the libraries for my compiler settings:

```
-lboost_exception
```

However, now it is saying that it is unable to find the boost_exception library. Which is interesting because I am able to see it in the file system!

I am wondering if I am doing the right thing or am I forgetting to add something to my compiler settings? Any help will be much appreciated!

Edit:

Here is the code:

```
// MS compatible compilers support #pragma once

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
# pragma once
#endif

//  boost/throw_exception.hpp
//
//  Copyright (c) 2002 Peter Dimov and Multi Media Ltd.
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See
// accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
// http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)

#include <boost/config.hpp>

#ifndef BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS
#include <exception>
#endif

namespace boost {
namespace serialization {

#ifdef BOOST_NO_EXCEPTIONS

inline void throw_exception(std::exception const & e) {
    ::boost::throw_exception(e);
}

#else

template<class E> inline void throw_exception(E const & e){
    throw e;// Error occurs here
}

#endif

} // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

Here is a code sample where the breakage occurs

```
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include "boost/serialization/vector.hpp"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream ofs("/home/phillip/test.txt");
    std::vector<std::string> tests;
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << tests;
}
```

Comment: Can you add source code sample you are compiling? What is your compiler?

Comment: I am compiling with gcc

Comment: Normally, you need to link serialization library via -lboost_serialization. That is correct. You do not need to link exception library now. So far it looks as boost paths problem. Can you post full output of your compilation with "-v" gcc flag added? It is better to see all errors/warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this happen when linking to the boost library when compiling with a different compiler/version/flags.

E.g. many Boost Serialization answer programs wouldn't link when compiling with Clang on [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com) whereas they'd run fine when compiling with Gcc

Comment: I compiled the boost library with gcc

Comment: Make sure it is using the same flags. Otherwise, like @pe3k the most likely cause is that the compiler is finding a different version of the library in another path (and that library was (compiled using) a different version of boost/gcc/flags). Note that Boost.System is also a dependency.

Comment: so the flags that I use to compile my program, I should use to compile boost?

Comment: ok, thanks for letting me know, I will try this once I get a chance. Maybe this weekend? For now, I downloaded a version of the boost library using sudo apt-get and everything works. It is running 1.58. I am only using this so that development will not be hindered but prefer to use the latest version